# Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, mismatch

When I try to run the following `INSERT INTO` query, the following message comes up:

> "Data Type Mismatch in Criteria expression"

I have had a look at all my fields and they are the same (Short text). I am wondering if it is the "Where condition". Do I need to have this field in my table where the information is being inserted into?

This is my `INSERT` CODE

```
INSERT INTO Fauna_ATT ( [Burn ID], [Burn Name], [Value Effected], [Pre Burn Action Details], [During Burn Action Details], [Post Burn Action Details] )
SELECT [Burn ID], [Burn Name], [Value Effected], [Pre Burn Action Details], [During Burn Action Details], [Post Burn Action Details]
FROM EPFP
WHERE ATT="TRUE";
```

Comment: I have taken out the "Where condition" and it seems to work fine. But I do need this condition in as I only want records copied over when there is an ATT required

Comment: What DB is this? Show also declaration of `Fauna_ATT` and `EPFP` - what is the type of `ATT`?

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: Presumably the error message is saying that one of the columns has an incompatible type.  That is where I would start looking for an issue.

Comment: Why are you copying records and not just using a query?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ATT` is a yes/no type field, don't use quote marks. TRUE and FALSE are intrinsic Boolean constants holding values of -1 and 0 respectively. If you enclose in text delimiters then the value is a literal string.

`WHERE ATT=True`

or

`WHERE ATT=-1`